# Nadirashvili surface (part 2)

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-numbers

The article is 'Hadamard and Calabi Yau conjectures on negatively curved an minimal surfaces' Nadirashvili.
In the proof of proposition 4.3 it asserts that the function y is holomorphic.
I'm not sure about it (actually i think it is false). What do you think about it?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, this part is wrong as stated, although the ideas behind it are sound. Pascal Collin and Harold Rosenberg did a great service to the community by publishing the note

> P. Collin and H. Rosenberg, *Notes sur la démonstration de N. Nadirashvili des conjectures de Hadamard et Calabi-Yau*, Bull. Sci. Math. 123 (1999), no. 7, 563–575.

in which they clarify and correct various details. In particular, the appendix of this note contains a cleaned-up proof of Proposition 3.4, which provides the missing details concerning the zeroes of the various functions involved.

References: [Collin-Rosenberg](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S000744979900113X), [Nadirashvili](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs002220050106) (also [preprint](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~esiprpr/esi262.pdf)), and [first part of this discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294399/nadirashvili-surface).