# Nadirashvili surface (part 3)

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry

The article that I'm considering is '[Notes sur la démonstration de N. Nadirashvili des conjectures de Hadamard et Calabi-Yau](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S000744979900113X)' by Pascal Collin and Harold Rosenberg. In the proof of the appendix (of proposition 4.3 of Nadirashvili article) the authors consider a polynomial approximation (uniform approximation) of the logaritm of a non zero function $ \varphi $ (on $E$). Now $ \log \varphi $ is well defined on $E$ but in general is not holomorphic (for the problem of the 'branch of the logaritm'). Now the only theorems that i know about polynomial approximation are Runge's therem and its generalization (Mergelyan's theorem). The first requires analyticity on whole $E$ while the second requires analyticity on the interior of $E$ (and continuity on whole $E$). But i don't think that this hypothesis is satisfied by $ \log \varphi $.
P.S. I'm grateful with 5PM for his collaboration.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the point you made [earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294399/nadirashvili-surface#comment642299_294675): the domain $E$ should be chosen so that it contains all of the poles of $d$ in $D_1$, which are denoted $z_1,\dots, z_n$ here. At the same time, $\overline{E}$ should contain no zeroes of $d$. Since both zeroes and poles form discrete sets, it is possible for $E$ to wiggle between them, grabbing some, avoiding others, and staying simply connected. Then I think the argument works exactly as it is written:

Since $\varphi$ is holomorphic and does not vanish on $E$ (*est holomorphe non nulle sur E*), and $E$ is simply-connected (*simplement connexe*), there is a single-valued branch of $\log \varphi$, which of course is a holomorphic function on $E$. It extends continuously to $\overline{E}$ since $d$ has no zeros or poles there. By Walsh's theorem we can approximate $\log\varphi$ on $E$ by a polynomial $h$ so that $h(z_k)=\log \varphi(z_k)$ for all $k$. Then the function $d_1=\prod_k (z-z_k)^{-1} e^h$ satisfies the conditions (‡).

Comment: The key fact to prove is that $ \varphi(E) $ does not intersect a ray $ l_\theta $ emanating from the origin of the complex plane for some $ \theta \in [0,2\pi) $. I don't understand why this fact is true (it must be true but i'm not able to see it).

Comment: @user55449 You don't need such a ray. Omitting a ray from the origin is an easy *sufficient* condition for having a single-valued branch of logarithm, but it is not necessary. Since $\varphi$ does not vanish, $\log \varphi$ is defined locally in $E$. Since $E$ is simply connected, these local patches can be put together into a single-valued holomorphic function. This is the [Monodromy theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monodromy_theorem).

Comment: I have reflected about the use of monodromy theorem and i have some doubt about it. The function $\log $ is well specified if we specify the set of values of $ \arg $. In  detail $ \log z= \log|z| + i \arg(z) $ where $ \arg(z) \in (\theta_0,\theta_0+2 \pi) $ give a different function for every choice of $ \theta_0 $. Foe every $ \theta_0 $ that we want to choose $ \log \varphi $ is well defined and continous on $ E $ since $ \varphi \neq 0 $ on $ E $.

Comment: @user55449 We use one branch of $\log$, does not matter which one. Such a branch exists by the monodromy theorem.

Comment: It's clear that if we choose $ z_0 \in E $ we can find a small neighbourod of $ z_0 $ in $ E $ where $ \log \varphi $ is analytic (for some choice $ \theta_0 $). Now if i understand what we want to do is to use Monodromy theorem for obtaining a global analytic continuation of $ \log \varphi $ on $ E $. For applying this theorem we have to check that $ \log \varphi $ can be analitically continued along any arc from $ z_0 $ to any point $ z \in E $. But how can we make sure about this fact?

Comment: @user55449 The logarithm of $\varphi$ can be analytically continued as long as $\varphi$ is holomorphic and does not attain the value $0$. Along every arc we have a continuously changing value of argument and of logarithm.

Comment: I have some doubt because we know that for a choosen branch $ \log $ of the logaritm ( for a choosen $ \theta_0 $) $ \log \varphi $ is analytic on a neighbourod $ U_0 $ of $z_0$ but  i'm not sure that i can analitycally continued  $ \log \varphi $ (for this choosen branch of the logaritm) along an arc joining $ z_0 $ to a point $ z $ outside $ U_0 $. If we change the branch along the arc we are working with no fixed function, so at the end what function have we extended?

Comment: I'm not sure about the continuation of $ \log \varphi $ outside $ U_0 $ because it can happen that for some point $ z $ outside $ U_0 $ $\varphi(z) \in l_{\theta_0}$ where $ l_{\theta_0} $ is the ray on which $\log $ is not analytic. Perhaps these doubts are related to something that i don't know about complex analysis

Comment: @user55449 I think your confusion comes from thinking about some $\theta_0$. Forget $\theta_0$. We don't need the values of argument to lie in any fixed interval $(\theta_0,\theta_0+2\pi)$. // What we do is fix a starting point $z_0$ and a branch of $\log \varphi$ at that point. Then we can extend logarithm along every path in the domain. By the monodromy theorem, this defines a holomorphic function. // Here is [an explicit statement of this fact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Logarithms_of_holomorphic_functions).